# Python problem with sockets

Tags: python, http, sockets

I'm working on a simple project involving sockets. Kinda like telnet. I just want it to connect to port 80 and execute GET /
Here is what I'm trying:

```
import socket
size = 100000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = "localhost"
port = 80
s.connect((host, port))
stuff = "GET /"
s.send(stuff)
r = s.recv(size)
print(r)
```

I run it, it connects but I don't get the output of GET /

Comment: Have you tried `GET / HTTP/1.1`?  RFC2616 seems to require the protocol version in the Request-Line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP spec says that you need two newlines (`'\r\n' * 2`) after the header. Try:

```
stuff = 'GET /\r\n\r\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need at least a blank line after the `GET /`, so use `stuff = "GET /\n\n"`. Read [this example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_protocol#Client_request).

Answer (score 1):

your main problem is lacking a newline after "GET /".  The HTTP protocol demands a newline, so the server is waiting for it, which is why you're waiting for a response.

(A minor problem is that your buffer size is too large, the Python socket module recommends a small power of 2 like 4096.)

I suggest:

```
import socket
size = 4096
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = "localhost"
port = 80
s.connect((host, port))
stuff = "GET /\n"
s.send(stuff)
buf = ''
while True:
    r = s.recv(size)
    if not r: break
    buf += r

print(buf)
```

The loop at the end assures you'll get the entire response.

And finally, I recommend urllib2, which implements HTTP for you and avoids such bugs:

```
import urllib2
print(urllib2.urlopen('http://localhost').read())
```